# Is the answer wrong: linear algebra done right Ex. 2B Q4

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the [answer](http://linearalgebras.com/2b.html). The underlined vector is the place where I am confused.

[image]
Beware the little ~ before the equation, It is not a minus sign.

In part (a):
$$U=\{(z_1, 6z_1, -2z_4-3z_5, z_4, z_5) \in \mathbb{R}^3\}$$
Then the solution to part (a) is $(1,6,0,0,0), (0,0,-2,1,0), (0,0,-3,0,1)$ **why the answer is  $(1,6,0,0,0), (0,0,2,-1,0), (0,0,3,0,-1)$?** (just multiply $-1$?)

In part (b)
**Should the answer be $(1,6,0,0,0), (0,0,-2,1,0), (0,0,-3,0,1), (0,1,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0,0)$ since we need to add $z_2$ and $z_3$? (This is how I think. Some dimensions are missing, and then add them back. Please correct me if I am wrong.)**

Comment: There is no difference between $(0,0,2,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,-2,1,0)$ as a basis vector. If $\vec{a}$ is part of a basis set, so is $\lambda \vec{a}$ for any $\lambda \neq 0$. And why do you think some dimensions are missing?

Comment: @stressedout The "dimensions" thing is about part (b) where it asked us to extent the basis in part (a) to $\mathbb{C}^5$ part (a) is only $\mathbb{C}^3$

Comment: OK. I get it now. Well, you have found $3$ vectors so far but you need $5$. So, you should add two linearly independent vectors to your current set of $3$ vectors. There are many ways to do this. Your book chooses an easy way: check the two most obvious ones: $(1,0,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,0,0)$. If they work (i.e. they're linearly independent from the other three), you're done. Now the only thing that's left to check is whether they're linearly independent or not. Can you proceed from there? To know whether it's wrong or not you should check whether the proposed set is linearly independent or not.

Comment: @stressedout My ans is $(0,1,0,0,0) , (0,0,1,0,0)$ because, my thinking was, because $6z_1 = z_2$ the $z_2$ dimension is "removed", and then if I need to add it back, I need to add $(0,1,0,0,0)$; similarly because I have made $(z_3 = -2z_4 - 3z_5)$ the $z_3$ dimension is "removed", and the to add it back, I add $(0,0,1,0,0)$ So I don't understand how to see in a obvious way that $(1,0,0,0,0)$ works.

Comment: There are many ways to obtain a basis for a vector space. A vector space doesn't have a unique basis, so it's possible to find many different bases for the same vector space. If you think your answer works, you should prove that the set you have found is linearly independent and it spans the space. If this condition is satisfied, your answer is correct. Otherwise, it's not. And just because your answer is correct, it won't disprove other answers because as I said, there always exist different bases for the same vector spaces.

Comment: @stressedout got it!

Comment: $U$ is most definitely _not_ $\mathbb C^3$. It is a three-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb C^5$. Try to get out of the bad habit of calling any old three-dimensional complex vector space “$\mathbb C^3$.”